# Calling MS Graph API from Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to use ADF pipeline to call MS Graph API (get user by email) by passing a set of userPrincipalName values from a Source (eg: Azure Table Storage)? Please provide an example.

This is what I have tried: I added Office 365 Linked Service. I have a copy data activity to copy data to Table Storage. Then I have added a Web activity. What dataset should I include in the settings? Also, how would I pass values from Azure Table Storage to Web activity?

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you've tried already, an where you've run into issues?

Comment: Please see updated question